# Investigate Canceled API Calls

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, request-cancelling

Investigating what may be causing api calls to be randomly "Canceled".
We are using axios in a React codebase.  We see ERR_NETWORK in the axios error, but what are some things that could cause this?  A lot of times we see a successful CORS response from the server, but the POST is still Canceled.  Sometimes, it is while the POST is in flight.

I have been trying to see if we should be looking at any of the following:

- withCredentials is used so something with the Cookies in the request?
- React Router is used - can this cause an api to get cancel if you do a history.push() while it is in flight?
- Is it likely that the browser is canceling these due to an HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR?  Not sure that there is any way to get data around this as we don't have direct access to our customers, and it has been a nightmare to replicate.